# js event loop: safari vs chrome

Tags: javascript, browser

In my html I have the following code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('click')
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  while(true);
})
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Dkf37ayTUExQ4/giphy.gif" alt="">
<div id='click'>
  click me!
</div>
```

Very simple event listener that triggers some blocking code.

If I click this div in chrome, the gif continues to animate; however, if I click this div in safari, the gif stops animating.

My understanding of the event loop is that chrome should pause the gif as well. In the event loop, it picks up the fact that it must do a task on the subsequent loop after the click.

As soon as the task has been finished, then it can continue onto the loop to reach the render steps.

It seems in safari, this is honored. In chrome, however, the render steps appear to continue to happen despite being locked in a blocking loop.

### Question

What is happening in the chrome interpreter that is different from how safari interprets it?

Comment: I suspect this is left implementation-dependent in the Javascript spec, and you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: firefox also pauses the gif

Comment: left implementation-dependent?

Comment: It seems like Safari uses separate threads to implement GIF animation and JavaScript code, so the JavaScript event loop doesn't affect animation.

Comment: it does in the case of safari, it looks like, because it can't rerender

Comment: I mean Chrome has separate threads.